# Как интегрировать JSON API в Prometheus?

Tags: json, api, curl, prometheus, grafana

Имеется API к сервису, посылаются GET запросы, и необходимо вытащить из JSON ответа необходимую информацию в Prometheus, а далее в Grafana.

```
{'status': True, 'signings': '105', 'company': {'name': 'ООО "Company"', 'inn': '0000000000', 'kpp': None}}
```

Необходимо вытащить из Json **signings** вывести в Grafana, чтобы данные хранились в течение 7 дней.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Постараюсь решить вашу задачу.
Возьмем библиотеку requests для отправки GET запроса к API и получения ответа в формате JSON.

```
import requests

response = requests.get(API_URL)
data = response.json()
```

Применим метод json() для преобразования ответа в формате JSON в словарь Python.

```
signings = data['signings']
```

Применим библиотеку prometheus_client для создания метрики gauge и установки значения signings.

```
from prometheus_client import Gauge

signings_metric = Gauge('signings', 'Number of signins')
signings_metric.set(signings)
```

В конце нужно запустить сервер Prometheus, чтобы собирать метрики, и настроить интеграцию с Grafana для отображения данных в виде графиков. Обязательно настройте время хранения данных 7 дней.

Comment: можете пожалуйста подсказать, возможно ли добавить к метрике - название компании, так как запрос не один?

Comment: Да, можно, используй метод labels() из библиотеки prometheus_client.:

company_name = data['company']['name']
signings_metric = Gauge('signings', 'Number of signins', ['company_name'])
signings_metric.labels(company_name).set(signings)

Comment: возникает ошибка при запуске ValueError: Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry: {'signings'}

Answer (score 0):

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge
import time
import requests
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
orgs = {
    'company1': 'api1',
    'company2': 'api2',
    'company3': 'api3',
    'company4': 'api4'
}
stats_podpislon = Gauge('podpislon', 'Podpislon statistics', ['org', 'type'])
def get_stats():
    for org in orgs.values():
        url = 'https://podpislon.ru/integration/get-info'
        headers = {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'x-api-key': org
        }
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = req.json()
        name = data['company']['name']
        stats_podpislon.labels(name, 'signings').set(data['signings'])
        if org == 'api4':
            time.sleep(10)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    # Generate some requests.
    while True:
        get_stats()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).